# Anyone has sample code that makes WMI queries to the CIM_DataFile class?

Tags: .net, wmi

Something that does SELECT's to get info about a file or directory? Something that actually works?

Language doesn't matter, I'm most interested in the query syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reached the answer, and it was all caused by a silly error of mine: I was failing to double the backslashes in the path string, and thinking it was being done. Additionally, you have to specify all four fields in the WHERE clause: drive, path, filename, and extension.

Answer (score 4):

Here're some examples:

- Querying a file:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM CIM_DataFile WHERE Name='C:\\WINDOWS\\NOTEPAD.EXE'
  SELECT * FROM CIM_DataFile WHERE Drive='C:' AND Path='\\Windows\\' AND FileName='Notepad' AND Extension='EXE'
  ```
- Querying a folder:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM CIM_Directory WHERE Name='C:\\Windows'
  SELECT * FROM CIM_Directory WHERE Drive='C:' AND Path='\\Program Files\\' AND FileName='Internet Explorer'
  ```

For more information on the query syntax, see [WQL (SQL for WMI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606.aspx). Also see [`CIM_DataFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387236.aspx) and [`CIM_Directory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387248.aspx) for a list of file and folder properties that can be used in the `SELECT` and `WHERE` clauses.

Answer (score 1):

The [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en) has some help.
See this code:

```
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2") 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
    "SELECT * FROM CIM_DataFile",,48) 
For Each objItem in colItems 
    Wscript.Echo "-----------------------------------"
    Wscript.Echo "CIM_DataFile instance"
    Wscript.Echo "-----------------------------------"
    Wscript.Echo "AccessMask: " & objItem.AccessMask
    Wscript.Echo "Archive: " & objItem.Archive
    Wscript.Echo "LastAccessed: " & objItem.LastAccessed
    Wscript.Echo "LastModified: " & objItem.LastModified
    Wscript.Echo "Manufacturer: " & objItem.Manufacturer
    Wscript.Echo "Name: " & objItem.Name
    Wscript.Echo "Path: " & objItem.Path
    Wscript.Echo "Readable: " & objItem.Readable
    Wscript.Echo "Status: " & objItem.Status
    Wscript.Echo "System: " & objItem.System
    Wscript.Echo "Version: " & objItem.Version
    Wscript.Echo "Writeable: " & objItem.Writeable
Next
```

**EDIT**

This sample is that you are looking [Enumerating All the Files on a Computer](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/guide/sas_fil_fjqz.mspx?mfr=true).

Try this format of query to:

```
Select * From Win32_Directory Where FileName = 'Scripts'
```

Here more info about make query [WQL using LIKE](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/topics/win2003/like.mspx).
Try this also: [Scriptomatic 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12028) .

Comment: A query that gets every row (i.e. any file) does me no good. I need a WHERE clause to get info from only one file.